# When exectuting a array rotation Python code it gives the error TypeError

Tags: python, arrays, typeerror

I've been learning from Geeksforgeeks.org and tried to write this C code into python and run it

```
    """
    recursive implementation

"""
#arr = []
def leftRotate(arr, d, n):
    # Return if number of elements to be rotated is zero or equal to array size
    if(d == 0 or d == n):
        return
    # if number of elements to be rotated if exactly half of array size/
    if ( n - d == d):
        swap(arr, 0, n-d, d)
        return
    # if A is shorter
    if(d < n-d):
        swap(arr, 0, n-d, d)
        leftRotate(arr, d, n-d)
    else: # if B is shorter
        swap(arr, 0, d, n-d)
        leftRotate(arr[0]+n-d, 2*d-n, d)

def printArray(arr, size):
    i = 0
    for i in range(size):
        print("%d"% arr[i], end=' ')
    print("\n")

def swap(arr, fi, si, d):
    i = 0
    temp = list
    for i in range(d):
        temp = arr[fi + i]
        arr[fi + i] = arr[si+i]
        arr[si + i] = temp

# Driver program to test above function
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
leftRotate(arr, 2, 7)
printArray(arr, 7)
```

Upon running this code it says a error saying TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

> [Running] python
>   "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py" 
>   `Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py", line 38,
>   in <module> leftRotate(arr, 2, 7)`
>
> File "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py",
>   line 17, in leftRotate leftRotate(arr, d, n-d)`
>
> File "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py",
>   line 17, in leftRotate leftRotate(arr, d, n-d) `
>
> File "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py",
>   line 20, in leftRotate     leftRotate(arr[0]+n-d, 2*d-n, d)   `
>
> File "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py", line
>   12, in leftRotate swap(arr, 0, n-d, d)  `File
>   "b:\Shall\Practice\Geeksforgeeks.org\recursiveblockswap.py", line 32,
>   in swap temp = arr[fi + i]`
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.209 seconds

Comment: Side note: you have lists, not arrays.

Comment: Did not dig into the details, but in the  leftRotate(arr[0]+n-d, 2*d-n, d) you are passing integer to leftRotate instead of array, as arr[0]+n-d in the first argument will be an int.

Comment: @StanleyKirdey you should repost your comment as an answer.

Comment: yes I know I have lists, it gave me that error before so that's why I changed the `arr` variable but still I'm not getting what's going wrong

Comment: @StanleyKirdey when I tried passing `arr` as an  array and not integer it gave me TypeError: can only concate list (not "int") to list

Answer (score 0):

`leftRotate(arr[0]+n-d, 2*d-n, d)` in this you are passing an integer value to the variable `arr` this is causing an error at `temp = arr[fi + i]`

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
```

basically means that you are accessing index of an int object.

Side Note:

in python you can swap values using

```
arr[1], arr[2] = arr[2], arr[1]
```

Comment: After changing that too `arr[fi+i], arr[si+i] = arr[si+i], arr[fi+i]` I'm still getting the same error on that particular line of code

Comment: the swap won't fix the bug in your code. It's just an improvement to the swap function.

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are passing an integer to `arr` variable. And then you are calling an index on an int variable. hence getting that error. Change `leftRotate(arr[0]+n-d,` to `leftRotate(arr,..`. The code will run after that.

Comment: Once you make that change improve your algorithm. Your algorithm is buggy. Also use a lot of prints, they will help you understand what value you are getting at which place in your code.